# Как правильно добавить элементы в такой массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В момент перебора массива, раз в цикл из массива извлекаются 3 значения: typeN, nameN и valueN. Как правильно добавлять их в новый массив, чтобы получить примерно такую структуру, которую я указал ниже?:

```
var arrayNew = {
 'type1': {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3'},
 'type2': {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3'}
};
```

У меня получилось что-то вроде такого, но нормально это не работает:

```
arrayNew[typeN] = {nameN: valueN};
```

Comment: `arrayNew[typeN] = {[nameN]: valueN};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то:

```
if(arrayNew[typeN] === undefined)
    arrayNew[typeN] = {[nameN]: valueN};
else
    arrayNew[typeN][nameN] = valueN;
```

Comment: Работает, только вместо {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3'} всегда получаю {'name3': 'value3'}.

Comment: @MikeRo обновил ответ